# Store column name in an extra cell

Tags: excel-formula

By now, I use something like `=function(tablename[[Columnname]:[Columnname]])`. Is there an (easy) way to store `Columnname` in cell `X1` and use something like `=function(tablename[[X1]:[X1]])`

My table named `tablename`:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
   1       a
   2       b
   3       c
   4       d
```

Cell `A1` = `ColumnA` <-the string

Cell `B1` = `=COUNTA(tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]])`

Cell `A2` = `ColumnB` <-the string

Cell `B2` = `=COUNTA(tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]])`

My aim is that the formulas in `B1` and `B2` use the values in `A1` and `A2`.

What I tried yet is something like: `=COUNTA(tablename[[INDIRECT(A1)]:[INDIRECT(A1)]])`

Comment: Yes there is a way.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Yes, I could tell you how.

Comment: Please tell me how

Comment: Just as soon as you show original effort at trying to solve the problem yourself, a [mcve] and ask a specific question.

Comment: @Jeeped I guess by my update I did so? Or is still something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INDIRECT function converts a text string to a usable cell reference or in your case a structured (list object) table name.

```
=VLOOKUP(K3, INDIRECT(J3), 3, FALSE)
```

[image]

In my sample worksheet illustrated above, J3 is a Data Validation List with a source of AA2:AA3. K3 is a typed value and L3 contains the formula. If J3 is switched to *Table1* then L3 becomes 66.

Comment: In your answer you read-in a value (K), which should be found in a table. What I'm about is, that you read-in a value (b), which specifies the column to work with. Example: count the values in column a, b, c

Comment: to COUNTA the values in Table2[b], put `b` in j4 and use `=COUNTA(INDIRECT(J3&"["&J4&"]"))`. result: **8**.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed. (I don't know if you want to add it to your answer)